# SourceTree and Git

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm new to git and not familiar with source control. Kinda confuse when I come to git and not sure how to fully utilize its benefit while most of the time, tutorial and informations is too complicated. Can anyone please summarize a short list on how to use the source tree (GUI Based Git Tool) perform and commit and code merging?

What I need to know and when to click the button of commit, checkout, stash, fetch, pull, push, branch, merge, and tag. How can I compare and merge the code, in my experiment it shown something couldn't understand if I merge it immediately. Because I don't know how to compare the code. Thanks

**Update & Resources**
Here are some researches done by me, with references and links to pick git up quickly ;)

1. [Try Git by Github (Fastest way to learn git)](http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1)
2. [Git commands cheatsheet](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html)
3. [Git commands cheatsheet (summary of 1st link)](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_git_developer_cheatsheet.pdf)
4. [Merge Diff Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460198/best-free-3-way-merge-tool-for-windows)

Comment: Thanks for providing the links you found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [merge or rebase article](http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/08/21/merge-or-rebase/) is a good introduction on those operations with SourceTree.

The merge itself is covered by [this support answer](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/18817/how-to-merge-with-sourcetree-git-without-command-line): in case of conflicts:

> The conflicted files are marked with an exclamation mark in a yellow triangle.
>   **You can see the diff on the right when you select the file, and you can see the diff against the two different parents by selecting 'Diff Parent' or 'Diff Merged' in the top bar of the diff area**.

More generally, you can set a [diff tool for code comparison purpose](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/150136/side-by-side-compare-with-inline-changes):

> click on the '`External Diff`' button in the top-right.
>   Which diff tool is used is configured in `Tools > Options > Diff` (Windows) or `Preferences > Diff` (Mac).